# Flutter/Firebase/url_launcher/ how to send SMS message from the app?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am developing a mobile app with Flutter.

I am just wondering how to send an SMS message from the app.

```
NewCustomIconButton(
  text: 'SMS',
  icon: Icons.sms,
  onPressed: () async {
    await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
        text:
            "Hello, ${confirmedBooking.userAccountID},  you have booking with ${_artistAccount.getFullname()}, "));
    UrlLauncher.launch(
        "sms://${confirmedBooking.phoneNumber}");
    },
  ),
)
```

In this code, if I press the button, it goes SMS screen on my phone, however, I am just wondering if it is possible that sending an SMS message without manually typing the text.

Thanks for reading,

I am waiting for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to send an `SMS` directly from the code, you could use the [sms](https://pub.dev/packages/sms) package:

*NB: the `sms` package supports only Android as for now*

```
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

SmsSender sender = new SmsSender();
String address = someAddress();
SmsMessage message = new SmsMessage(address, 'Hello from Flutter!');
message.onStateChanged.listen((state) {
  if (state == SmsMessageState.Sent) {
    print("SMS is sent");
  } else if (state == SmsMessageState.Delivered) {
    print("SMS is delivered");
  }
});
sender.sendSms(message);
```

If you'd like to open a new `SMS` message prefilled with specified content and recipient, you could do so by launching the following `URI`:
`sms://${confirmedBooking.phoneNumber}?body=${messageBody}`

Remember to encode the `String` to get a valid `URI`:

```
String uriAndroid = "sms:${confirmedBooking.phoneNumber}?body=${messageBody}";
String uriIOS = "sms:${confirmedBooking.phoneNumber}&body=${messageBody}";
uriAndroid = Uri.encodeFull(uriAndroid);
uriIOS = Uri.encodeFull(uriIOS); // valid URIs
```

For reference, follows a full code snippet according to your specific scenario:

```
NewCustomIconButton(
     text: 'SMS',
     icon: Icons.sms,
     onPressed: () async {
       String smsContent = 
               "Hello, ${confirmedBooking.userAccountID},  you have booking with ${_artistAccount.getFullname()}";
       await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
           text: smsContent));
       String char = Platform.isAndroid ? '?' : '&';
       UrlLauncher.launch(
           Uri.encodeFull("sms:${phoneNumber}${char}body=${smsContent}"));
     },
   ),
)
```

I'd also suggest to create a reusable function:

```
void createNewSms(String phoneNumber, String smsContent) {
 String char = Platform.isAndroid ? '?' : '&';
 UrlLauncher.launch(
     Uri.encodeFull("sms:${phoneNumber}${char}body=${smsContent}"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it`s actually not working properly. It is sending message to "1234567890?body=hello,daegil,youhavebookingwithemiendo" this number.

Comment: onPressed: () async {
                            String messageBody =
                                "Hello, ${confirmedBooking.userAccountID},  you have booking with ${_artistAccount.getFullname()}, ";
                            String uri =
                                "sms://${confirmedBooking.phoneNumber}?body=$messageBody";
                            UrlLauncher.launch(Uri.encodeFull(uri));
                          },

Comment: I've updated the code to address the issue!

Comment: Thank you so much, it was really useful!  However, it`s actually not exactly what I am asking. I was actually asking about the sending SMS message in App, it also goes to the message screen as well with the body message, and I have to manually press the send button as well. I think what i want is technically impossible :). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy to help! I've modified the answer to include new findings, including a way to send an SMS directly from the app (on Android). Please let me know if this helps